# Installing Windows 7 on a Lenovo Thinkpad Z61m 9450HAG

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad

I am currently thinking about updating my laptop's OS from Windows XP to Windows 7.

I know that I will need a clean installation to achieve this upgrade.

Has anyone ever tried to install Windows 7 on a Z61m? Are there drivers available (I couldn't find them on the Lenovo site)? What other problems could I run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 uses the same driver model as Vista so at a push you should be able to get stuff working using the Vista drivers.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience there is a problem with the video driver - you will have a bad resolution and won't be able to change it!

Answer (score 0):

I prowl the Lenovo forums quite a bit, and it seems they are waiting for the actual release date till releasing drivers and also help with windows 7 drivers

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Windows 7 since February on my Z61m Model 9450-GDG. Everything works fine, go ahead and install it. You won't regret it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the second time I've formatted my z61m with Windows 7; everything is working perfectly. All the drivers you need are included in the base Windows 7 installation.

All I can say is that Windows 7 works well with the z61m. Your Windows Experience Index will be 3.2/7 since this is determined by the lowest feature of your computer (in this case the GPU), so is alright.